# How can an OpcUa client get info about server configuration? Like max-pending-publish-requests etc

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

My MILO OpcUa client was working fine, until I reached certain amount of subscriptions - 10. Then it started receiving `Bad_TooManyPublishRequests`. I resolved the issue by setting `OpcUaClientConfigBuilder#setMaxPendingPublishRequests = 10;` as suggested by [this answer](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/issues/76), and it is working fine again.

**But how should I know beforehand, that the server is only able to handle 10 pending publish requests?**

After connecting to sever, I can read some server information. As *ServerState*, *CurrentTime*, or *ServerProductName* as it is shown in `ReadExample#readServerStateAndTime`. But how can I get servers *MaxPendingPublishRequests*, *MinSamplingInterval* settings etc?

Also what is the relation between Subscription and MonitoredItem? I used one MonitoredItem per Subscription, which seems to be bad approach now. If you want to monitor hundreds of Nodes, should they be in one Subscription, or divided in more Subscriptions? Should they be grouped by `publishingInterval`, or what is the right logic to group them?

Edits are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will split up your question and provide answers to you.

> But how can I get servers MaxPendingPublishRequests, MinSamplingInterval settings etc?

To read the value of `MinSupportedSamplingRate`, you can make use of the Attribute Read services of OPC UA. The nodeId of `MinSupportedSamplingRate` node is `ns=0;i=2272`. Using the attribute read service, you can read the value attribute to get the minimum supported sampling interval of the server.
If you are using a GUI client, you can browse through the server address space to find its value. It is present under `Root->Object->Server->ServerCapabilities->MinSupportedSamplingRate`

> “Also what is the relation between Subscription and MonitoredItem?”

Subscriptions are used to report notifications to the client. Subscriptions have a set of MonitoredItems assigned to them by the Client. MonitoredItems generate Notifications that are to be reported to the Client by the Subscription

> “If you want to monitor hundreds of Nodes, should they be in one Subscription, or divided in more Subscriptions?”

One subscription is enough to monitor hundreds of Nodes (or even more). It depends on your use case.

> Should they be grouped by publishingInterval, or what is the right logic to group them?

The publishing interval of a Subscription defines the cyclic rate at which the Subscription executes. Each time it executes, it attempts to send a NotificationMessage to the Client. NotificationMessages contain Notifications that have not yet been reported to Client.

If in case, the subscription is created with a publishing interval of 1ms, then every 1ms the server sends a notification message, which can either be

1. a data change notification if any value changes has occurred or
2. an empty notification response if there are no value changes (only if keep alive interval is elapsed)

It is not necessary that the nodes must be grouped by publishing interval parameter.

Here are some other open source implementations that you might be interested in trying out:

- **open62541** – https://open62541.org/certified-sdk.html – C stack | Mozilla License | Embedded ready | TSN ready
- **NodeOPCUA** – https://node-opcua.github.io/ – NodeJS | MIT License | Cloud ready
- **FreeOpcUa** – https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua – C++ | LGPL-3.0 License | Python bindings
- **UA .NET stack** – https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard – RCL License for corporate members of OPC Foundation & GPL 2.0 for others | Standard profile | Web oriented implementation
- **Eclipse Milo** - https://github.com/eclipse/milo - Java | EPL 2.0

If you are looking for more hands-on information, you can also check out these resources:

- **Free documentation:** You can look at the open source documentation page: https://open62541.org/doc/current/
- **Paid online course:** Practical introduction to OPC UA – code walk-through and examples in this course use the open62541 stack: https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/practical-introduction-to-opc-ua-part-i

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. One minor change: a subscription with a publishing interval of 1ms will not necessarily send a notification every 1ms. If nothing is changing, it will not send an empty “keep alive” response until the configured keep alive interval has elapsed.

Comment: Thank you Priyadharshini and @Kevin for clarification. It helps a lot. I can get now the _MinSupportedSamplingRate_ but still cannot find Node holding the maximum number of queued publish requests _MaxPendingPublishRequests_. Or how else should the client be configured to not get the `Bad_TooManyPublishRequests` response?

Comment: Unfortunately these values are not published in any standardized way by the server. The Milo client does allow you to configure some max value though, so you'll just have to pick a max that you find to work experimentally. However if you change your code so that you are no longer using 1 subscription per item you are not likely to run into this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. That is exactly the answer I was looking for. 

What will be the recommended setup, if I have bunch of Nodes where values change exactly every 5 minutes, and another bunch where values change can be randomly milliseconds to hours apart ? (Subscription settings, and MonitoredItem setting, ...)

Comment: @Štarke you can use a single subscription with a fast Publishing Interval (e.g. 100ms or 1000ms) and then varying Sampling Intervals for all the items that belong to it. It won't be a problem. Whether you eventually need another subscription probably depends on the number of monitored items you will have. Some servers may limit the number of monitored items per subscription. Unfortunately this will be another unpublished value.